# Replace root element only with different name - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have got stuck with minor change for XSLT, because i would like to replace the Top root node with different name. I have tried with below XSLT to add new root, but unable to delete the initial root of input xml. Can someone please let me know what i am missing here. Thank you.

Below is the XSLT code tried.

```
                     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

                        <xsl:template match="root">
                            <ns:NewParent xmlns:ns="http://test.com/user">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                            </ns:NewParent>
                        </xsl:template>

                        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:template>
```

Input XML :

```
                    <root>
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA</a>
                            <b>Testb</b>
                            <c>Testc</c>
                        </root>
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA1</a>
                            <b>Testb1</b>
                            <l>Testl1</l>
                        </root>
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA12</a>
                            <b>Testb12</b>
                            <l>Testl2</l>
                        </root>
                    </root>
```

Output/Desired XML :

```
                    <ns:NewParent xmlns:ns="http://test.com/user">
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA</a>
                            <b>Testb</b>
                            <c>Testc</c>
                        </root>
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA1</a>
                            <b>Testb1</b>
                            <l>Testl1</l>
                        </root>
                        <root>
                            <a>TestA12</a>
                            <b>Testb12</b>
                            <l>Testl2</l>
                        </root>
                    </ns:NewParent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template matching `root` does `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` which copies the node itself, as well as all children. You should do `<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />` instead.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <ns:NewParent xmlns:ns="http://test.com/user">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </ns:NewParent>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that you wouldn't need the identity template in this case. Just this template would do. If you did want to use the identity template, or if you needed to transform other nodes, use `xsl:apply-templates` instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <ns:NewParent xmlns:ns="http://test.com/user">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ns:NewParent>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how the template now matches `/root` so that it only matches the top level `root` element, and not its children.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim :) got it. Appreciate your help.